# MediaWiki API executing JavaScript from URL parameters

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I've noticed a concerning behavior in my MediaWiki installation's API endpoint (api.php) where it seems to be executing JavaScript code passed as URL parameters directly.

For instance, when I make a request like this:
http://wiki.loc/api.php?action=help&modules=alert(document.cookie)
Instead of treating the JavaScript code (alert(document.cookie)) as plain text, it seems to execute it, triggering an alert with the user's cookie data.

This behavior raises significant security concerns as it opens the door to potential Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

I've reviewed the request handling code in api.php, but I couldn't find any immediate solution to prevent this behavior.

Could someone please provide insights into why MediaWiki might be executing JavaScript from URL parameters and how to mitigate this security risk effectively?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: How are you calling the endpoint? MediaWiki itself is running on the server, in PHP, so isn't "executing" the JavaScript; only something in the browser can do that.

Comment: It also sounds like this could be a bug / support request for the software, rather than a programming question, which [makes it off-topic here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746), and you should raise it at their [Support Desk](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Support_desk) or [bug tracking system](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/How_to_report_a_bug).